# What is the size of an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm-analysis

**Question:** Does the "size" of an algorithm typically refer to the number of its inputs, or its running time?

This seems an ambiguous term to me that I keep seeing in textbooks.

Comment: Can you give an example? I don't think I've ever seen a reference to the "size" of an algorithm.

Comment: Maybe you mean something along the lines of Kolmogorov complexity? Length of the smallest program calculating the same function?

Comment: Can you name any textbook that does this?

Answer (score 1):

In complexity theory, "size" refers to the length of (some string representing) the input to the algorithm. One is then interested in some cost measure of the work done (most commonly some upper bound) when processing input of a given size as a function of said size.